# How to apply Mod(,2Pi) to all solutions to equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code to solve the algebraic equations, but some solutions such as the first one and the second one means the same when we draw them on a circle. Thus I want to apply Mod(,2Pi) functions to all solutions in order to obtain unique solutions. Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
Solve[Sin[d12] + Sin[d13] == 0 && -Sin[d12] + Sin[d23] == 0 &&  Sin[d13] + Sin[d23] == 0 && Mod[d12 + d23 - d13, 2*Pi] == 0 && 0 <= d12 <= 2*Pi && 0 <= d23 <= 2*Pi && 0 <= d13 <= 2*Pi, {d12, d13,d23}]
```

```
{{d12 -> 0, d13 -> 0, d23 -> 0}, {d12 -> 0, d13 -> 0, 
  d23 -> 2 \[Pi]}, {d12 -> 0, d13 -> \[Pi], d23 -> \[Pi]}, {d12 -> 0, 
  d13 -> 2 \[Pi], d23 -> 0}, {d12 -> 0, d13 -> 2 \[Pi], 
  d23 -> 2 \[Pi]}, {d12 -> (2 \[Pi])/3, d13 -> (4 \[Pi])/3, 
  d23 -> (2 \[Pi])/3}, {d12 -> \[Pi], d13 -> 0, 
  d23 -> \[Pi]}, {d12 -> \[Pi], d13 -> \[Pi], 
  d23 -> 0}, {d12 -> \[Pi], d13 -> \[Pi], 
  d23 -> 2 \[Pi]}, {d12 -> \[Pi], d13 -> 2 \[Pi], 
  d23 -> \[Pi]}, {d12 -> (4 \[Pi])/3, d13 -> (2 \[Pi])/3, 
  d23 -> (4 \[Pi])/3}, {d12 -> 2 \[Pi], d13 -> 0, 
  d23 -> 0}, {d12 -> 2 \[Pi], d13 -> 0, 
  d23 -> 2 \[Pi]}, {d12 -> 2 \[Pi], d13 -> \[Pi], 
  d23 -> \[Pi]}, {d12 -> 2 \[Pi], d13 -> 2 \[Pi], 
  d23 -> 0}, {d12 -> 2 \[Pi], d13 -> 2 \[Pi], d23 -> 2 \[Pi]}}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the constraint ` Mod[d12 + d23 - d13, 2*Pi] == 0` ?

Answer (score 2):

Define the list of replacement rules as

```
sltn = Solve[
  Sin[d12] + Sin[d13] == 0 && -Sin[d12] + Sin[d23] == 0 && 
   Sin[d13] + Sin[d23] == 0 && Mod[d12 + d23 - d13, 2*Pi] == 0 && 
   0 <= d12 <= 2*Pi && 0 <= d23 <= 2*Pi && 0 <= d13 <= 2*Pi, {d12, 
   d13, d23}]
```

Check the dimensions of the list

```
sltn // Dimensions
```

Replace the abstract `d12`, `d13` and `d23` by their solutions and mod them like so:

```
Table[Mod[{d12, d13, d23} /. sltn[[i]], 2 Pi], {i, 1, 16}]
```

the outcome of which is

> 

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, π, π}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {(
  2 π)/3, (4 π)/3, (2 π)/3}, {π, 
  0, π}, {π, π, 0}, {π, π, 0}, {π, 
  0, π}, {(4 π)/3, (2 π)/3, (4 π)/3}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0}, {0, π, π}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: `Mod` is `Listable`. Use `Mod[{d12, d13, d23} /. sltn, 2 Pi]`

Comment: thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

If I remove the restrictions from the system to be solved except the one that `d12 - d13 + d23` is a multiple of `2 Pi`, I get a set of mod-$2\pi$ families of solutions, with each family having a unique base point on the unit circle.  I can replace the parameters `C[k]` with `0` to get just the desired base points:

```
sol = Solve[
    Sin[d12] + Sin[d13] == 0 && -Sin[d12] + Sin[d23] == 0 && 
     Sin[d13] + Sin[d23] == 0 &&
     Cos[d12 - d13 + d23] == 1, (* replace restrictions with Mod below *)
    {d12, d13, d23}
    ] /. _C -> 0
(*
{{d12 -> 0,       d13 -> 0,       d23 -> 0},
 {d12 -> 0,       d13 -> π,       d23 -> π},
 {d12 -> (4 π)/3, d13 -> (2 π)/3, d23 -> (4 π)/3},
 {d12 -> (2 π)/3, d13 -> (4 π)/3, d23 -> (2 π)/3},
 {d12 -> π,       d13 -> 0,       d23 -> π},
 {d12 -> π,       d13 -> π,       d23 -> 0}}
*)
```

Or I can replace `ConditionalExpression[s, cond]` with `Simplify[Mod[s, 2 Pi], cond]` to reduce the solution to just the base points:

```
sol = Solve[
    Sin[d12] + Sin[d13] == 0 && -Sin[d12] + Sin[d23] == 0 && 
     Sin[d13] + Sin[d23] == 0 &&
     Cos[d12 - d13 + d23] == 1, (* replace restrictions with Mod below *)
    {d12, d13, d23}
    ] /.
   ConditionalExpression -> (Simplify[Mod[#, 2 Pi], #2] &) //
  DeleteDuplicates
(* same output as above *)
```

The first method is simpler, but it assumes the base points are from `0` up to `2 Pi`. The second actually applies `Mod[-, 2 Pi]` as requested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DeleteDuplicatesBy` with an appropriate discriminator function that applies `Mod[#, 2 Pi]` to the right-hand side in each `Rule` (i.e. the value):

```
sol = 
 Solve[
   Sin[d12] + Sin[d13] == 0 && -Sin[d12] + Sin[d23] == 0 && 
    Sin[d13] + Sin[d23] == 0 && Mod[d12 + d23 - d13, 2*Pi] == 0 && 
     0 <= d12 <= 2*Pi && 0 <= d23 <= 2*Pi && 0 <= d13 <= 2*Pi,
   {d12, d13, d23}
 ];

DeleteDuplicatesBy[
  sol,
  Mod[#[[2]], 2 Pi] &
]

(* Out:
{{d12 -> 0, d13 -> 0, d23 -> 0},
 {d12 -> 0, d13 -> π, d23 -> π},
 {d12 -> 0, d13 -> 2 π, d23 -> 0},
 {d12 -> (2 π)/3, d13 -> (4 π)/3, d23 -> (2 π)/3},
 {d12 -> (4 π)/3, d13 -> (2 π)/3, d23 -> (4 π)/3}}
*)
```